# Responsive design not working on grid. TAILWIND

Tags: responsive-design, grid, tailwind-css

Tailwind is not working when I try to use different grid layouts depending on screensize. **It completely ignores the code if I put it after a md:, lg: or xl: tag.** This happens only when I try to change something that has to do with grid. Example:

`<div class="grid grid-cols-3 md:grid-flow-col">`

It only listens to grid-cols-3, applying it to every screensize despite my trying to control the layout.

- I've tried REINSTALLING without anything happening. Saw another stack overflow where that was ticked as the resolution for another user. Did not work for me.
- I've tried creating MANUAL CLASSES, adding media queries inside in my css file and calling that in the div, like this:

`<div class="grid grid-cols-3 trying-this">`

`@media (min-width: 768px) {  .trying-this { grid-auto-flow: column !important; } }`

- My version of tailwind is 3.2.1.

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? I'm completely stuck.**

Comment: `md:grid-flow-col` will be applied on screens that are bigger than `768px` while `grid grid-cols-3` will always be applied, where exactly is the problem? they don't contradict each other. Can you create a tailwind-play example showing the issue?

Comment: Check out this tailwind-play for example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/amR1L0ZiUo

Comment: Same issue... and then it randomly goes away and comes back.  I'm using Next js, so assume all the right files are being regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

tailwind must be running:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/input.css -o ./public/css/your-new-css.css --watch
```

after you save changes to your files, this process updates the your-new-css.css file with the things you intend to use.

(as in [the installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation))

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of css is defined by the order of class definition in the (generated) css file. The order in the class attribute is ignored and it is treated only as a set. Sometimes the ! may help, but that is usually just a workaround for some other issue.

In my case tailwind generated the media query before the ".grid-*" classes and hence the final result was not what I wanted. It turned out, the miss-order was due to the wrong @tailwind commands in my pcss files (utility and variants were flipped).
After fixing the order, all started to work by the book.

My order at the moment:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;
```